# How can I create labels for given input ID in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm Working on Northwind DB, I have a problem in MS Access.

I want to create labels for the dbo_Products with some fields. Till creating labels is fine but, if the User gives input as ("Ex. I Need labels for products with Id's in between 10 - 30") then the output should display labels only from 10 till 30. How can I do this operation ?

It should give outcome of specific labels as given by the User. I want to connect the data entry form to report such that if user clicks the button by inserting the ID values the labels in between the specified id's should appear.

Thank you. Your Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the filter property of the report to be "ID between 10 and 30".

Comment: I want to connect the data entry form to report such that if user clicks the button by inserting the values the labels in between the specified id's should appear. 

Sorry i didnt mention this above 
Thank You.